# Sql Server Trigger error: SqlException: Subquery returned more than 1 value.

Tags: sql-server, exception, triggers

I have a trigger that inserts into another table based on one of `INSERTED`'s values.

```
CREATE TRIGGER 
    [dbo].[triggerTest]
ON 
    [dbo].[Original]
AFTER INSERT
AS
  BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

      If (SELECT city FROM INSERTED) = 'LA' 
          INSERT INTO Hotel 
          SELECT price, quality FROM Inserted AS I
      ELSE IF (SELECT city FROM INSERTED) = 'NY'
          INSERT INTO Inn
          SELECT price, quality FROM Inserted AS I
END
```

I found that when I insert multiple rows into `Original` table, I get this error:

> SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=

What's the problem with above trigger?

Comment: triggers should be batch aware...

Comment: What should happen when you insert three rows into `Original` table with `city` values: `NY`, `LA`, `SF` (or anything else)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `INSERTED` table has more rows returned, So, you need `top (1)` with `order by` clause, but i would  `exists` instead :

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[triggerTest]
ON  [dbo].[Original]
AFTER INSERT
AS
  BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

      IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INSERTED WHERE city = 'LA')
          INSERT INTO Hotel (price, quality)
               SELECT price, quality 
               FROM Inserted AS I
      IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INSERTED WHERE city = 'NY')
          INSERT INTO Inn (price, quality)
               SELECT price, quality 
               FROM Inserted AS I
  END
```

Note :

- Always qualify column name explicitly while doing `INSERT` operation.

Comment: I guess there is similar `WHERE` predicate required in each part of insert. At least.

Comment: Thanks. It works well. But why `Always qualify column name explicitly` when columns in `Original` table and `Hotel`, `Inn` are the same?

Comment: @bbusdriver If you alter the table; for example if you add more columns to the table, the query will break if you haven't specified the column names